# Не получается стилизовать waveSurfer

Tags: javascript, аудио

[image: волна]

Использую waveSurfer.js
Уже все перепробовал, убил кучу часов, но стилизовать волну именно так не получается...
Может подскажет кто, как сделать на подобии?

Еще не удалось при "молчании" выводить просто прямую линию, выходят только пробелы...

Сейчас получается только как на этом скрине[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    let wave = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#waveform-' + key,
        waveColor: '#C4C1CA',
        progressColor: '#0084FF',
        cursorColor: '#FAFAFA',
        barminWidth: 0.2,
        barWidth: 10,
        barHeight: 1.3,
        barRadius: 5,
        cursorWidth: 0,
        height: 50,
        barGap: 0,
    });
    wave.load(/*ссылка на аудио*/);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Извиняюсь, дополнил свой вопрос